# Caption/Label for vertical line in Matlab histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, legend, caption

I use Matlab to plot some returns in a histogram. I would like to see the 0.005 quantile in the Plot via a vertical line This works with the following code

```
q = 0.995;
MSCIq = quantile(MSCIan, 1-q)

nbins = 50;
histMSCI = histogram(MSCIan, nbins)
xlabel('MSCI')
ylabel('count')
title('test')
line([MSCIq MSCIq], ylim, 'Color', 'r')
```

[image]

I would like to label the vertical line with a text and the value of MSCIq. (Say MSCIq= -0.44 then I would like to have something like "Value-at-Risk = -0.44"). Either directly at the line or in form of a legend. 
Does anyone know how to to this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hold on;
text(100, 300, 'MSCIq= -0.44');
hold off;
```

Comment: Thanks @SpamBot, but that doesn't work for me. No error but no caption either. Besides, is there any way to replace the value "-0.44" with the variable MSCIq in case the value changes?! Thank you!!

Comment: Use can generate the string argument from the value using `sprintf`. Also, please adapt the coordinates 100, 300.